# Getting Count when using DetachedCriteria/DistinctRootEntity

Tags: c#, nhibernate

update: After not getting anywhere with this, I noticed that when I pulled the queries out into two distinct criteria, the actual hydrated objects returned were correct, but the count query was returning the joined dataset.

So the question is: How do I use `Projections.RowCount` in conjunction with `CriteriaUtil.DistinctRootEntity` and a DetachedCriteria.

> I have two entities that are linked
>   via a many to many - Tags and Posts.
>
> For an admin screen, I would like to
>   return paged results, so I'm using a
>   multicriteria to pull back my objects,
>   as well as the counts:
>
> ```
> var multiResults = session.CreateMultiCriteria()
>     .Add(criteria.SetMaxResults(Top))
>     .Add(clone.SetProjection(Projections.RowCount())).List();
> ```
>
> One of the filters that I have on this
>   page is a DateLastUsed filter. Here, I
>   want to return a Tag only if it has an
>   associated post that that was posted
>   after a certain date.
>
> ```
> criteria.CreateAlias("AssociatedPosts", "p");
> var mostRecent = DetachedCriteria.For(typeof (Post),"p2").SetProjection(Property.ForName("CreatedDate").Max())
>                 .Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("p.id", "p2.id"));
>
> criteria.Add(Subqueries.Le(postedAfterDate),
> ```
>
> mostRecent));
>
> This seems to return the correct data
>   set, but **I'm returning a tag for
>   each post that it is associated
>   with**. The next step was to apply
>   `criteria.SetResultTransformer(CriteriaUtil.DistinctRootEntity)`
>   but this didn't seem to resolve the
>   issue.
>
> I saw these couple of links that
>   seemed to point towards a bug, but it
>   seems that its been fixed (we're using
>   2.0.1.4000).
>
> - [NH-1055 - Multi Criteria ignored Result Transformer](http://nhjira.koah.net/browse/NH-1055)
> - http://markmail.org/message/rp3qusnhwcdincfo
>
> Any ideas? First time I've played with
>   MultiCriteria, so I could be doing
>   something else weird (the other
>   filters are trivial).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After doing some further investigation, I stumbled upon this:

http://floledermann.blogspot.com/2007/10/solving-hibernate-criterias-distinct.html

The issue described is almost identical to the one I'm running into. The comments provide some good additional insight.

Comment: The blog is closed!
This link is broken.